# Utilizing jQuery Selectors to simplify HTML parser code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This code uses jQuery `find()` and several `if` statements to pick out certain text from an HTML document.

I'm trying to remove the `if` statements and interpret them to jQuery selectors in `find()`, at the very top line of code. Is this possible? If so, what would the selectors need to be?

```
$(document).find("a[href^='http://fakeURL.com/']").each(function()
{                                           
    var title = $(this).text();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    if(title.indexOf('Re: ') != 0)
    {
        if($(this).parent().attr('class') != 'quoteheader')
        {
            if(url.indexOf('topic') == 36)
            {
                if($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'middletext')
                    {

                        console.log(title);

                    }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last thing I left, you want to check if the topic is at index 36 ? not sure its possible via the selector, beside that everything went up to the selector (code not tested, should work tho)

```
$(document).find(".middletext:not(.quoteheader) > a[href^='http://fakeURL.com/']").each(function()
{
    if(url.indexOf('topic') != 36)
        return;

    var title = $(this).text();

    if(title.indexOf('Re: ') != 0)
        return;

    console.log(title);
});
```

Comment: you should just print the title inside the `if`. it's a waste getting the text outside the `if` statement and not inside.

Comment: regardless, you need to move the `$(this).text()` line to be inside your `if` statement. not outside.

Comment: @Ido Oops, I accidently removed my url variable when I posted the question. I've placed it back in the code now so it should make more sense. Can checking the index go in the selector now that you know how url is related to find()?

Comment: @Ido Also, the selector should select `a` elements that don't start with `Re: `. It looks like your solution is selecting only elements that *do* contain `Re: `

Comment: @Farad I've updated the code, I guess is the minimum statements that available ..

Comment: @Ido Can this (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector be used somehow to interpret the `if` statement that makes sure the title doesn't start with `Re: `?

Comment: No, because this selector is for attribute. and the only way to access the element's text via selector is :contains and :empty.